# My own 'jQuery'

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Why this[0][0].style.width = "" ? And my framework can't change value. How to make the function SetWidth work? The function SetWidth should change the value of CSS properties in class.

```
var Framework = function( nameOfClass ) {
    return new Framework.foo.init( nameOfClass );
}

Framework.foo = {
    init: function( nameOfClass ) {
        if (typeof nameOfClass === 'string') {
            nameOfClass = Sizzle(nameOfClass, document);
            this[0] = nameOfClass;
            return this;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },

    GetWidth: function() {
        return this[0][0].style.width;
    },

    SetWidth: function( nameOfClass, value ) {
        // ???
    }
}

Framework.foo.init.prototype = Framework.foo;

window.Framework = window.$$ = Framework;

//console.log(Framework('.mainBlock-fixsize'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth) property you're reading is a computed value, the sum of width and padding. So if you want `GetWidth` to return the same value you set with `SetWidth`, you'll have to pass two value to `SetWidth`, then change the element's `style.width` and `style.padding` properties.

Comment: It is strange. In my html code div have width 100px and clientWidth = 100 too.

Comment: If you do so, then it doesn't work: slyle.width = "".            GetWidth: function() {return this[0][0].style.width;} Why?

Comment: You may be looking for [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: Thank you.It does not suit me because everywhere receive item by ID, but I need to work not with the ID with classes.